# problem implementing a trait in a vector with rust

Tags: rust

I am studying and experimenting rust.
I wand to implement an abstract train 'GraphEntity' and then two more traits 'Point' and 'Triangle'.
I have the following code that works fine:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

trait GraphEntity {
    fn plot (&self) {
        println!("this is a plot!");
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Ord for Point {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        (self.x, &self.y).cmp(&(other.x, &other.y))
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for Point {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Point {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        (self.x, &self.y) == (other.x, &other.y)
    }
}

impl Eq for Point { }


#[derive(Debug)]
struct Triangle {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
    z: i32,
}


impl GraphEntity for Point {
    fn plot (&self) {
        println!("P:[{},{}]", self.x, self.y);
    }

}

impl GraphEntity for Triangle {
    fn plot (&self) {
        println!("T:[{},{},{}]", self.x, self.y,self.z);
    }

}

struct SetOfEntities {
       list: Vec<Box<dyn GraphEntity>>,
}

impl SetOfEntities {
    fn new () -> Self {
        Self {
            list: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    fn append<S: GraphEntity + 'static>(&mut self, entity: S) -> &mut Self {
        self.list.push(Box::new(entity));
        
        self
    }
    
    fn plot(self) {
        for x in self.list {
            x.plot();
        }
    }
}


fn main() {

    let p1: Point = Point { x: 1, y: 0 };
    let p2: Point = Point { x: -1, y: 2 };
    let t: Triangle = Triangle { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3};

    let mut set = SetOfEntities::new();
    set.append(p1);
    set.append(p2);
    set.append(t);
    set.plot();
}
```

I want now to change the append function and check if any existing point is already in the list.
If it already exists, I would not add to the list.

```
fn append<S: GraphEntity + 'static>(&mut self, entity: S) -> &mut Self {
    match self.list.binary_search(&entity) {
        Ok(pos) => self,
        Err(pos) => { self.list.push(Box::new(entity)); self },
    }
}
```

this gives me the following errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:70:39
   |
69 |     fn append<S: GraphEntity + 'static>(&mut self, entity: S) -> &mut Self {
   |               - this type parameter
70 |         match self.list.binary_search(&entity) {
   |                                       ^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::boxed::Box`, found type parameter `S`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&std::boxed::Box<dyn GraphEntity>`
              found reference `&S`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `dyn GraphEntity: std::cmp::Ord` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:70:39
   |
70 |         match self.list.binary_search(&entity) {
   |                                       ^^^^^^^ the trait `std::cmp::Ord` is not implemented for `dyn GraphEntity`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::cmp::Ord` for `std::boxed::Box<dyn GraphEntity>`
```

Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: Use enum not dynamic dispatch would be my advice.

Answer (score 0):

### Trying to fix errors

You have two errors:

1. The first is problem is easy to fix: `expected struct 'std::boxed::Box', found type parameter 'S'`. The `binary_search` function expects a box since `self.list` is a `Vec` of boxes. You can just change it to `self.list.binary_search(&Box::new(entity))`. (You might still have to help the compiler a bit to coerce it to the dyn type.)
2. The second error is a bit trickier and quite hard to solve. The problem is that `binary_search` needs objects that implement the `Ord` trait, but it only has knowledge of `GraphEntity` since the type of the objects are `dyn GraphEntity`.
   For most traits you could give `GraphEntity` a supertrait and this would be fixed, but unfortunately this doesn't work here because you can't make trait objects for `Ord`. You would get error [E0038](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0038), because this could be unsafe.
   My idea of a small fix was to create a `cmp` function in `GraphEntity` and use `binary_search_by` instead of `binary_search`. However `cmp` would have a `Self` parameter and this causes the same error. So as far as I know, you can't fix it the way you want.

If you can't fix your code in Rust, there's often something wrong with the logic of the code. I think this is the case here, because for `binary_search` you need to compare `dyn GraphEntity` objects. So you also want to compare a `Point` with a `Triangle`, which don't have a (partial) order relation.

### Using enum

As you probably can notice that Rust's dynamic dispatch is not made for (some) complex situations. Comparing objects of a different type is non-trivial. Implementing the same trait doesn't say anything about comparing them.

If the `binary_search` over `GraphEntity` objects is exactly what you want, than the best solution is probably using an enum. Rust will make sure you handle every case of comparing different types.
The compare function might look like this:

```rust
fn cmp(&self, other: &GraphEntity) -> Ordering {
    match (self,other) {
        (GraphEntity::Point(p1),GraphEntity::Point(p2))
            => (p1.x, p1.y).cmp(&(p2.x, p2.y)),
        (GraphEntity::Triangle(t1),GraphEntity::Triangle(t2))
            => (t1.x, t1.y, t1.z).cmp(&(t2.x, t2.y, t2.z)),
        (GraphEntity::Point(_),GraphEntity::Triangle(_))
            => Ordering::Less,
        (GraphEntity::Triangle(_),GraphEntity::Point(_))
            => Ordering::Greater,
    }
}
```

This can get really complex with more variants in the `GraphEntity` enum, but it can handle the complexity. While dynamic dispatch is better in handling modularity.

It seems like you tried to model your program as done in an inheritance based OOP language like Java or C++. Be careful with that, it is a mistake a lot of Rust beginners make, including myself.

Comment: "*but it can handle the complexity*" Solving the problem that way requires an exponential number of combinations plus all types must be known in advance. These constraints make it unusable for many systems.

Comment: "*an inheritance based OOP language like Java or C++*" While C++ supports inheritance (even multiple inheritance!), it is not "an inheritance based OOP language". Rust also provides support for some OOP concepts (including trait objects and inheritance on them), but it isn't an OOP language by any stretch.

Comment: "Solving the problem that way requires an exponential number of combinations plus all types must be known in advance. These constraints make it unusable for many systems." Yes, there will be an exponential number of combinations, but this will be the case for any method of your choice, however it does not mean you have to implement an exponential number of cases. And as long all types are known in advance, this is very much usable. (This doesn't mean it is the right choice, there is always a trade-off)

Comment: "While C++ supports inheritance (even multiple inheritance!), it is not "an inheritance based OOP language". " If you think C++ is not inheritance based OOP than you either don't know C++ or I confused you with the term "inheritance based OOP". I'll assume the latter. With "inheritance based OOP" I differentiate between the original idea of OOP which is without the notion of inheritance. Since C++ is an OOP language and, as you said, even has multiple inheritance, it is an inheritance based OOP language.

Comment: "Rust also provides support for some OOP concepts (including trait objects and inheritance on them), but it isn't an OOP language by any stretch." OOP is defined in different ways, but if I follow the original idea of objects having member variables that pass messages (via methods), than Rust is very much an OOP language. Rustaceans don't like to call it that, because OOP is linked to inheritance. (That is why I make a difference with "inheritance based OOP"). Even the rust book is agnostic about it: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-00-oop.html.

Comment: "*but this will be the case for any method of your choice {...} it does not mean you have to implement an exponential number of cases*" No, it can be done with O(n^2) cases. If done as shown here, you'd need to implement all. For 6 types, that is 64 vs 21 cases. And types might not be known in advance anyway.

Comment: "*it is an inheritance based OOP language.*" When you say "inheritance based OOP language" it looks like C++ code uses inheritance all the time to benefit from OOP, which is not true at all. If having inheritance is all is required for a language to be an "inheritance based OOP language", then all OOP languages would be so.

Comment: "*OOP is defined in different ways { ... } the original idea of objects having member variables that pass messages (via methods)*" . OOP is pretty well defined since the middle sixties or so, and includes inheritance as a key feature. Types having members and functions to operate on them does not make a language OOP. Even C would be considered to support OOP if that were true.

Comment: "For 6 types, that is 64 vs 21 cases."
Only if all 64 cases need a different implementation, which you would have to do in all methods used. If not, you can use pattern matching to generalize.
"And types might not be known in advance anyway."
Yes. I'm talking about the cases where they are as I mentioned before.

Comment: "When you say "inheritance based OOP language" it looks like C++ code uses inheritance all the time to benefit from OOP, which is not true at all."
I agree that my choice of the word "based" is wrong here. I basically mean OOP languages with inheritance.
"If having inheritance is all is required for a language to be an "inheritance based OOP language", then all OOP languages would be so."
No, OOP languages without inheritance would not be, like rust.

Comment: "OOP is pretty well defined since the middle sixties or so, and includes inheritance as a key feature." No it is never well defined (http://wiki.c2.com/?DefinitionsForOo) that is exactly the problem here. Ideas of orienting around "objects" have been around since the late 50s while inheritance was introduced in the late 60s. 

"Types having members and functions to operate on them does not make a language OOP. Even C would be considered to support OOP if that were true."

Comment: "Types having members and functions to operate on them does not make a language OOP. Even C would be considered to support OOP if that were true." No because C does not have methods, so no support for "message-passing" between objects. But yeah, you can use the ideas of OOP in C just like you can use the ideas of functional programming in C.

Comment: I mostly definitely agree with you, I think the disagreement is over fine points in semantics. For instance, while Rust has methods, encapsulation and dynamic dispatch; it does not have inheritance, many OOP patterns do not fit well and almost all Rust code favors static dispatch and composition only. That is why I don't consider Rust an OOP language by any means. Even C++, which supports inheritance, it is not used as an OOP language in many projects, for good reason.

Comment: Wrt the definition of OOP, from my experience in academia, almost nobody refers to a language without inheritance as OOP. From Wikipedia (since you quoted another wiki, I think it is fair :-), backed by a paper, we have statements like "*Simula introduced important concepts that are today an essential part of object-oriented programming, such as class and object, inheritance, and dynamic binding.*".

Comment: "*No because C does not have methods, so no support for "message-passing" between objects.*" Having `self` (or `context` or `handle`) parameters is used by most C libraries out there, including very old ones. It's different from other OOP features like inheritance, encapsulation or dynamic dispatch which cannot be emulated in C properly, even if some people do so anyway by playing tricks with function pointers, vtables, macros, etc. But message passing and methods? Those are definitely in C ;-)

Comment: "I mostly definitely agree with you, I think the disagreement is over fine points in semantics." Certainly! ;) Specifically the classification of programming languages.
"many OOP patterns do not fit well and almost all Rust code favors static dispatch and composition only." And that's a good thing, I think. However OOP is not defined by these patterns (unless you create a new definition). More so, some OOP patterns shouldn't even be used in OOP with inheritance. Also some of these patterns fit perfectly in Rust, like the builder pattern.

Comment: "Even C++, which supports inheritance, it is not used as an OOP language in many projects, for good reason." In many projects, it isn't, but in many more it is! I've seen a lot of inheritance abuse in the wild (in C++). Which is why I like Rust for leaving out inheritance. But the reason why I prefer making a difference between OOP and OOP with inheritance, is that your definition of OOP (and of many others) discredits OOP for all good things it has brought to handle complexity without inheritance. That's why I see Rust as OOP, because it inherited these good things and left out the bad thing.

Comment: "From Wikipedia (since you quoted another wiki, I think it is fair :-), backed by a paper, we have statements like" That is certainly fair ;) but that paper was written in 1994 and at that time, the disadvantages of inheritance were not that clear yet. So it uses the same definition as you do.

Comment: Let me quote the same wiki page: "OOP is a programming paradigm based on the concept of "objects", which can contain data and code: data in the form of fields (often known as attributes or properties), and code, in the form of procedures (often known as methods)." No mention of inheritance in the short summary of what OOP is. Also: "Terminology invoking "objects" and "oriented" in the modern sense of object-oriented programming made its first appearance at MIT in the late 1950s and early 1960s." This was before Simula introduced inheritance.

Comment: "Having self (or context or handle) parameters is used by most C libraries out there, including very old ones." But this is emulating OOP using C features, just like "people playing tricks" is emulating OOP. I assume you mean with "cannot be emulated" that it isn't exactly the same and user unfriendly, but the same can be said for "methods" in C.

Comment: "But message passing and methods? Those are definitely in C" I disagree, a method may be a normal function with its object as (first) parameter under the hood, but it doesn't mean every function is a method to its parameter. A Rust function and method can have the exact same signature, but that does not make the function a method. You can however use it as such.

Comment: "*but that paper was written in 1994 and at that time, the disadvantages of inheritance were not that clear yet.*" It doesn't matter that OOP has disadvantages (or advantages), the definition hasn't changed. For almost anything, you can always find a few authors using non-standard terms in some publication, but the point is almost everybody imply inheritance and other bits when they say "OOP language".

Comment: From an ACM article linked in Wikipedia: "*the definition of an <object-oriented programming language> is not exactly the same as that of a <programming language with object-oriented features>.*". That's exactly what I am saying: Rust is not an OOP language, even if it has OOP features. C++ isn't either, and that one even has inheritance!

Comment: "*This was before Simula introduced inheritance.*" Of course, people always start using terms before a definition in literature is settled, that is not surprising. The sentence isn't implying OOP may mean something else or that OOP doesn't include inheritance.

Comment: "*A Rust function and method can have the exact same signature, but that does not make the function a method.*" Yes, but that is Rust terminology. The concept of "method" in OOP is an abstract one. For example, when I am providing a C ABI for my Rust or C++ libraries, most of the code is boilerplate to expose the methods (member functions)  of my types (classes), even if C does not have a "method" term in its standard nor supports "classes".

Comment: "It doesn't matter that OOP has disadvantages (or advantages), the definition hasn't changed." It does matter since there are multiple defintions. "For almost anything, you can always find a few authors using non-standard terms in some publication, but the point is almost everybody imply inheritance and other bits when they say "OOP language"." There are more people than you think using a different defintion. Even wikipedia uses different definitions in its OOP page! There clearly is no consensus.

Comment: "From an ACM article linked in Wikipedia", I can't find that quote, can you state your source?

"C++ isn't either, and that one even has inheritance!" If you actually think C++ is not OOP than you are using a different definition for OOP than you are defending here. By all definitions I know, C++ is very much a OOP language. The whole existence of the language is based in making C with OOP (and inheritance if using my preferred definition).

Comment: "The sentence isn't implying OOP may mean something else or that OOP doesn't include inheritance." It implies that a different definition existed before the one with inheritance, which points out that it is not a must to have inheritance in OOP.

Comment: "even if C does not have a "method" term" Exactly C does not have methods, but you still call Rust methods, because methods are procedures. You were stating before that C did have methods though!